# Deploying website to Azure: Each time requires cleaning the cached content to see the updated website [ASP.NET + REACT]

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, azure, caching

I am deploying my site to Azure from VS 2017. After each deployment, I am supposed to clean the cache of my browser to get the latest version of the website (or use ctrl+f5 to ignore the cached content when refreshing). But, this is a problem for the end users.

This is a `asp.net + react` website. So, the client-side code is cached in the browser. I have `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` set to 0, but did not help. Any suggestions? Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

In VS 2017 right-click on the project and choose Publish. Click on Configure, then make sure the box is ticked for "remove additional files at destination"

I don't have enough votes to post screenshots yet, sorry!